# Import brainwallet.io Address to Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, brain-wallet

A while ago I created an address and private key on brainwallet.io now I would like to add those to my bitcoin-qt wallet. I don't see an easy way to do that in the interface nor with the cli importXXX commands. How do I do this?